# Git commit user is different than git push user

Tags: git, bash, bamboo

I get a very strange behaviour. I have a bash script that runs on Bamboo, which sets the desired git user, commits some changes, then pushes them to the master branch.

The problem is that, the commit is done with the correct user, but the push is done with a different user.

The commit looks something like:

```
USERX authored commit 7d365...
```

And then the push:

```
USERY pushed to master at user/repo
```

The commit and push are done one after another after setting the username and email, so why is this happening, what should I look for? Here's part of my bash script:

```
git config user.name "$bamboo_GIT_USER_NAME"
git config user.email "$bamboo_GIT_USER_EMAIL"

git add -v CHANGELOG.rst || exit 3
git commit -v -m "Updated CHANGELOG.rst" || exit 3
git push origin "$bamboo_GIT_BRANCH" -v || exit 3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Commits are actual things (specifically, "objects") that live inside the git repository.  They contain text strings giving the author and committer.  Once written into an object, these are permanent and unchangeable.

- Aside: `git commit --amend` does not change them; instead, it makes a new, *different* commit, with different data in the commit, and points the branch-head to the new commit:

  ```
  ... - E - F - G   <-- master
  ```

  If you then `git commit --amend --author='someone else <someone@else.where>'`, git abandons the old tip commit (`G`), adding a new commit (`G'`):

  ```
  ... - E - F - G   [abandoned]
              \
                G'  <-- master
  ```

When you do a `git push`, this does something very different.

Let's say, for instance, you first `git fetch` some commits written by someone else, from a repository at `git://else.where/path/to/repo.git`.  Or, you write your own commits with `user.name` and `user.email` set to some unusual values.

- Aside: your example code has a `git add` but no `git commit`.

Then you `git push` these commits (written by someone else, or committed with odd `user.name` and `user.email`) to `ssh://mylogin@some.place/different/path/to/repo.git`.

Here, you package up the commits you retrieved, and deliver them to your other server.  But it's *you* (specifically, `mylogin`) logging in via ssh to `some.place`, delivering the commits; the commits you deliver are the permanent, unchangeable repository objects you retrieved from `else.where`, or made under the settings you put in `user.name` and `user.email`.

Note that git *does not* authenticate you or log you in to the host `some.place`.  It's ssh that authenticates you and logs you in, as you (or rather, `mylogin@some.place`).  Your ssh session then runs the git command that receives the git objects you send.  If you ask, on `some.place`, what user is running ssh, you get `mylogin`: that's who logged in via ssh.  This is completely disconnected from the author and committer names stored in the commits being uploaded.

Comment: I've corrected my question, forgot to add the `commit` command. Okay, so what should I do in this case to prevent pushing with a different user name?

Comment: Git doesn't have a user name in pushing, as git doesn't care.  Other things—ssh, for instance, or programs that log the user who is invoking them—are what care.  You need to find out how to get those *other* programs to believe that you are someone that you're not.  This has all kinds of security implications, of course: what's to stop some random person on the Interweb from pretending to be you?  However, the simplest thing in many shell scripts is to override `$USER` in the environment (which must be done outside of git—again, git itself doesn't care, and doesn't do that).

Comment: Alright. And if these commands are run by Bamboo, how can I check/where should I look to see which user executes the commands and thus is considered the one who pushed the commits?

Comment: I've never used Bamboo and know nothing of its own internals, so can't really help there.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I'll investigate further how can I solve the Bamboo problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to be like that.

To change the author of the last commit:

```
$ git commit --amend --author='somebody <somebody@example.com>'
```

Comment: It is not supposed to be like that, why is it? I set the user name and email and expect both the commit and push to be executed by that user, why does it change?